# @PropertySource values overriding

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to have 2 external files for my app config, one with common properties for all my apps and one with specific things for each app.

In my Springboot App, I declare :

```
@PropertySource(value = {"file:/etc/company/application.properties",
        "file:/etc/company/myApp/application.properties"}, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

In logs,

```
Converting PropertySource applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties] [org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedMapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
Converting PropertySource URL [file:/etc/company/myApp/application.properties] [org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
Converting PropertySource URL [file:/etc/company/application.properties] [org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
```

And the properties from **/etc/company/application.properties** are the ones taken into account..
This is the exact inverse of what is mentioned in PropertySource javadoc.

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many investigation, it seems that neither Spring or Spring Boot ensure the order of property source loading.
I did remove my properties inheritance : 1 app, 1 app.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

A known workaround is renaming `application.properties` to something else (e.g. `app.properties`). Overriding works normally then.

But I admit this is not a proper fix to this issue and might not work in some scenarios.

Source: a comment by Maksim Muruev (mmuruev) in [@PropertySource not overriding in order [SPR-13500]](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18078#issuecomment-711850211).